# Postgresql error : PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql

In the Datastore logs, I encountered the following error, Not sure what has gone wrong.

```
[7804] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2021-08-23 22:56:15.980 CEST [7804] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 9003
2021-08-23 22:56:15.983 CEST [7804] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "10.91.198.36", port 9003
2021-08-23 22:56:16.041 CEST [8812] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-23 22:54:51 CEST
2021-08-23 22:56:16.044 CEST [8812] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2021-08-23 22:56:16.045 CEST [8812] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2021-08-23 22:56:16.076 CEST [7804] LOG:  startup process (PID 8812) was terminated by exception 0xC0000409
2021-08-23 22:56:16.076 CEST [7804] HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2021-08-23 22:56:16.078 CEST [7804] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-08-23 22:56:16.094 CEST [7804] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Your system is corrupted.  The corruption event would have been logged, if at all, in some previous log file, not this one.  This is the one where the corruption was discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody deleted crucial WAL files (to free space?), and now your cluster is corrupted

Restore from backup. If you have no backup, running `pg_resetwal` is an option, since it seems there was a clean shutdown.